# How do I position geometry in Threejs to the bottom maintaining its aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to Threejs and facing a problem in the positioning of geometry. I want to position geometry at the bottom and it should be half cut i.e like half area should be visible but when try adding `position.setY(-300)`, it moves down but stretches the geometry. I don't know what I am doing wrong or what will be the correct way to position the geometry without losing its aspect ratio. Can some help me to solve this?

I am also attaching the link of fiddle and code: [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/piyushwalia/fcqjfqvp/2/)

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, muesum;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 600;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(350, 2);

  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    wireframe: true,
  });

  muesum = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(muesum);
  muesum.position.setY(-300);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  muesum.rotation.x += 0.001;
  muesum.rotation.y += 0.002;
  renderer.clear();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes,  I don't want. Just want to move geometry to the bottom

Comment: @piyushwalia Consider reducing the field-of-view of the perspective camera. https://jsfiddle.net/fcqjfqvp/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call "losing its aspect ratio.", is the perspective projection, of an big object, that is very close to the camera.

If you don't want that, then you have to use the [`OrthographicCamera`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/OrthographicCamera), which creates an orthographic projection matrix and projects the scene parallel on the viewport.

See the Example:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, muesum;

init();
animate();

function updateCameraProjection() {
    var aspect    = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var wndHeight = 700;
    camera.right  = aspect*wndHeight/2
    camera.left   = -camera.right;
    camera.top    = wndHeight/2;
    camera.bottom = -camera.top;
    camera.near   = 1;
    camera.far    = 1000;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera();
  updateCameraProjection();
  camera.position.z = 500;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(350, 2);

  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    wireframe: true,
  });

  muesum = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(muesum);
  muesum.position.setY(camera.bottom);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function onWindowResize() {
    updateCameraProjection();
    muesum.position.setY(camera.bottom);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  muesum.rotation.x += 0.001;
  muesum.rotation.y += 0.002;
  renderer.clear();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
```